# What is "?" combined with " :" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi I really don't understand what's the "?" combined with ":" in a same sentence

Example :

```js
 var c = myFunction(); 
var b = c + 3; 
var a = b ? c : 1; 

console.log(a); 

function myFunction() {

return 3; 

};
```

In a real code what does it mean ?

Comment: It's called a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), it's a very shorthand way of writing if/then/else.

Comment: Ah okay thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It's a ternary operator, shorthand for an `if`/`else` statement.

This:

```js
var a = b ? c : 1;
```

Is essentially:

```js
var a;
if(b){
    a = c;
} else { 
    a = 1;
}
```